# How to save overpy query to .osm?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, overpass-turbo, osmnx

I am using `overpy` to collect data information about taxiways, taxilanes and parking positions of an airport (icao code LOWW). I was able to achieve my goal I wrote the following lines of code:

```py
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()
r = api.query("""
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“taxiway in airport ”
*/
[out:xml]/*fixed by auto repair*/[timeout:25];
// fetch area “airport” to search in
area[icao~"LOWW"]->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “aerodrome”
  node["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);
 
  // query part for: “taxiway”
  node["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
 
  // query part for: “taxilane”
  node["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);
 
  // query part for: “parking_position”
  node["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);
 
);
// print results
out meta;/*fixed by auto repair*/
>;
out meta qt;/*fixed by auto repair*/
""")
```

However my goal is to save the response into the .osm file format. Unfortunately i cannot find in the `overpy` documentation a way to do it.
Would you be able to suggest a way to achieve my goal?

**NOTE**: I was thinking to use other packages as well such as `osmnx` but i cannot get the query as right as with overpy.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('wien flughafen austria', infrastructure='way["aeroway"]',simplify=False, custom_filter = ('["aeroway"~"taxiway|taxilane|parking_position"]'))
ox.save_load.save_as_osm(G, filename='filename.osm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the `overpy` package to retrieve raw OSM from overpass API.

You can do direct http calls like in the following, using `requests` library. We also provide the solution to both write the XML and continue parsing the result with `overpy` like if you would have made it without `requests`

You need to change following `useragent` variable to 'Your website or application name/your contact' like illustrated here https://github.com/riccardoklinger/OSMquery/issues/34#issuecomment-423730819 to comply to ToU

```py
import overpy
import requests

useragent = 'Your website or application name/your contact'
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome 80"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'User-Agent': useragent,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://overpass-turbo.eu',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'https://overpass-turbo.eu/',
    'Accept-Language': '',
    'dnt': '1',
}

query = """
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“taxiway in airport ”
*/
[out:xml]/*fixed by auto repair*/[timeout:25];
// fetch area “airport” to search in
area[icao~"LOWW"]->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “aerodrome”
  node["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="aerodrome"](area.searchArea);

  // query part for: “taxiway”
  node["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);

  // query part for: “taxilane”
  node["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="taxilane"](area.searchArea);

  // query part for: “parking_position”
  node["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="parking_position"](area.searchArea);

);
// print results
out meta;/*fixed by auto repair*/
>;
out meta qt;/*fixed by auto repair*/
"""

data = {
  'data': query
}

response = requests.post('https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter', headers=headers, data=data)

with open('/tmp/myquery.osm', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)

api = overpy.Overpass()

results = api.parse_xml(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer that is exaclty was I was looking for. Do you perhaps know a way to make such request directly to openstreatmap?

Comment: Please don't use a fake User-Agent identifier in your own Python scripts, as it violates the ToU. Change it to your project name + contact details.

Comment: @mmd Made an edit to mention your comment (abusive use of copy to CURL in my browser debugger network panel, sorry). Better?